# ¿cómo hacer para que todos los elementos dentro de un div hereden el margin-left?

Tags: css3

Tengo una serie de elemtos mas o menos asi:

```
<div class="container1">    
        <div class="elemento1 comun"></div>
        <div class="elemento2"></div>
        <div class="elemento3 comun"></div> 
        <div class="container2">
            <img class="elemento4">
        </div>              
</div>
```

Con estas propiedades:

```
body
{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.container1
{
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    margin-left:50px; /*importante que el margen sea el mismo para todos*/
    overflow:hidden;    
}

.comun
{
    height: 300px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.elemento2
{   
    height: 300px;
    width: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.elemento3
{
    margin-left:250px;
    width: 300px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.container2
{
    display:table;
    position:relative;
}
```

Algunos de estos elementos (el 1, 2 y 3) los muevo con las coordenadas del ratón (solo de derecha a izquierda o viceversa).

Todo funciona bien siempre que "container1" tenga la propiedad "margin-left" con el valor correcto referente al borde izquierdo del body.

El problema aparece cuando quiero centrarlo todo en la página junto a un formulario que tengo mas abajo con mas elementos dentro de un div principal (contenedor).

```
<div class="contenedor">

  <div class="container1">  
        <div class="elemento1 comun"></div>
        <div class="elemento2"></div>
        <div class="elemento3 comun"></div> 
        <div class="container2">
           <img class="elemento4">
        </div>              
   </div>   

  <form>
    Mas elementos....
  </form>

</div>
```

Por el momento la clase para el div "contenedor" la tego hecha así:

```
.contenedor
{
    display:table;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Pero así existe un desfase al mover los elementos  (1, 2 y 3) con el ratón que depende del "margin-left" del "container1".

¿Alguna forma de declarar la clase ".contenedor" para que "container1" herede su propiedad "margin-left"?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Perdón pero he leído varias veces la pregunta y no alcanzo a comprenderla. Puedes agregar imágenes de lo que tienes y lo que quieres lograr?

Comment: Hola, he añadido una imagen... (es un cropper)... lo único que quiero es poder meterlo todo en un mismo contenedor para centrarlo en la página y que sea responsive. Lo que pasa es que al hacerlo la propiedad margin-left se pierde para los elementos que están dentro de él... gracias y saludos!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Llevo intentando con CSS un par de horas y no hay manera... :-( Por el momento lo he hecho con JavaScript para salir del paso.aunque he tenido que prescindir del "contenedor" y centrar directamente "container1"... aquí dejo la funcion por si a alguien le ayuda.

```
function centrar_container()
{
    container = $(".container1");

    var cw = parseInt(container.css("width"));
    var ww = parseInt($(window).width());
    var dw = ww - cw;
    var margin_left = parseInt(dw/2);
    container.css("margin-left", margin_left + "px");
    console.log(cw + " " + ww + " " + margin_left); 
}
```

En cualquier caso si alguien sabe como hacerlo en CSS y pone aquí su respuesta la aceptaré encantado, ya que era la pregunta que en un principio hice.